# How to remove duplicated values from list view JavaFx?

Tags: java, listview, user-interface, javafx

I have two RFID readers representing two different rooms , with RFID tags representing `walletName`. When passing a tag by any reader I should see the (tag) `walletName` in the specified room `ListView` (reader) that the tag passed by, so it could be in `roomAList` / `roomCList`. Here I am trying to prevent the duplicated values in case of passing the tag twice on the same reader, so I should have gotten the `walletName` just once displayed in `roomAList` but instead it is being duplicated as shown in picture [GUI snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLDLo.png).
I thought of clearing the `listView` but it wasn't a good idea because there could be other non-duplicated values inside it.

I also want to clear the `walletName` from `roomAList` if it moves to `roomCList`.

```
if (wallet_Location.equals("RoomA") && (!roomAList.getItems().contains(walletName))) {
    roomAList.getItems().add("> " +walletName+"'s wallet");
    //roomAList.getItems().clear();
}

else if (wallet_Location.equals("RoomC") && (!roomCList.getItems().contains(walletName)){                       
    roomCList.getItems().add("> " +walletName+"'s wallet");
}
```

Comment: The `Collection#contains(Object)` method is based on `Object#equals(Object)`. This is a problem for your implementation as `walletName` will **never** be equal to `"> " +walletName+"'s wallet"`, thus `contains` will always return false. The items of a `ListView` should be the model while the `ListCell` is responsible for displaying the model—look into configuring a [cell factory](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#cellFactoryProperty()) to add the desired prefix and suffix. That being said, consider creating a dedicated model class. [cont.]

Comment: If you do create a dedicated model class don't forget to properly implement both `Object#equals(Object)` and `Object#hashCode()` so that instances can be safely used in collections. You'll want to configure a cell factory in this case as well. As for removing elements from one list when equal elements are added to another, just [add a listener](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#addListener(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener)) and react appropriately.

Comment: Thinking about the bigger picture, if your application uses an architecture such as MVC, MVP, MVVM, or whatever then your (view-) model could hold the wallets in a `Set`. By definition, a `Set` disallows duplicates.

Comment: Would a `Set` work?